# cannot convert 'const ScalarMultipleReturnType Error

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen

Running my code gives the following compilation error:

> cannot convert 'const ScalarMultipleReturnType {aka const Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp, const Eigen::Matrix >}' to 'double' in initialization
>      double tempSum = deltaT*(vectorB(i)-vectorB2(i))*k[i];

at the following line:

```
double tempSum = deltaT*(vectorB(i)-vectorB2(i))*k[i];
truncError = truncError + tempSum;
```

I have defined variables vectorB and vectorB2 as: `Eigen::VectorXd vectorB;` and initialized as `vectorB  = Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(size);` for both vectors respectively.

k is defined as: `std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> k(size);`

deltaT is of type `double`

Each Even though k is a vector of Matrices, each matrix has only one value. eg: k[0] is a single double value.

Can someone please help me with the type conversion here? I think that's what's causing the issue. I wish to convert the RHS of the expression `double tempSum = deltaT*(vectorB(i)-vectorB2(i))*k[i]` into a double variable.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Eigen -- however you are doing a vector multiplied by a matrix, so the result of that would be another vector, so it doesn't make sense to convert vector to double.  Can you give some example inputs and outputs to show what you are trying to calculate?

Comment: @MattMcNabb No, I am multiplying a single element in the vector, i.e. `(vectorB(i)-vectorB2(i))` by a single element matrix, so according to me, the return type should be `double`. Like I mentioned, `k[i]` is a single element matrix.

Comment: Normally, subtracting two vectors gives another vector. Why do you expect it to give one element?  Also: a one-element matrix is different to a scalar, your last comment suggests you are treating those two as interchangeable.  (IDK whether Eigen has implicit conversion from a single-element matrix or not, but if so, it'd have to only work when the matrix size was known at compile time)

Comment: To get a good answer you will need to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You should be able to get it down to 10 lines or so, since it is a compiler error.

Comment: vectorB(i) is a single element of vectorB of datatype Eigen::VectorXd. Similarly for vectorB2(i). This basically runs in a loop, where it accesses individual elements of vectorB and vectorB2 using variable i.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried creating a temporary matrix i.e. `Eigen::MatrixXd temp = k[i];` and since I know that k[i] is a one element matrix, I used it in the expression as `double tempSum = deltaT*(vectorB(i)-vectorB2(i))*temp(0,0);` and it works okay. This is a very crude fix, though, and a very specialized solution.